# Java Key Listener Not Able to Get Window Focus

Tags: java, swing

I have the following code:

```
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            isRunning = false;
        }
    });
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(width * scale, height * scale);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    while (!frame.hasFocus()) {
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.requestFocus();
    }
    frame.addKeyListener(new KeyManager());
```

I am trying to listen for keys using the key listener. The problem is - it only works roughly 1 / 10 times. Why? Can someone give me a fix? I thought it was a problem with the window's focus, but I don't understand how my window could not have focus (because of the loop).

KeyManager is a class that extends KeyAdapter and contains the appropriate methods.

Comment: Use Key Bindings as it will allow you to get around all this focus mess. Google for the tutorial and/or search for similar questions and answers on this site for more and for examples (some written by me).

Comment: You're forced focus loop isn't going to help

Comment: ... and some examples written by @MadProgrammer as well, including [MadProgrammer examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A992484+keylistener+body%3Abindings) and [my examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A522444+keylistener+body%3Abindings)

Comment: As it was already said, you are better off using Key Bindings. From the above code, get rid of the loop. Also maybe using `requestFocusInWindow` instead of `requestFocus` will yield the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If any component in your frame has focus then it will not run a key listener for the frame, and because the component is inside the frame, the frame will still be returning true for `hasFocus()`.

To fix this you can add a KeyListener on all components or you can use [jnativehook](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/) or you can use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) (probably the best fix).

Notice: I am assuming you have components on your JFrame.